# How to convert this SQL Server 2016 query to BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

For the open data: [bigquery-public-data:stackoverflow.posts_questions], I like to get the stats of all available tags and I am using lagacy SQL Dialect:

```
SELECT tags AS Category, COUNT(*) AS TotalCat
FROM [bigquery-public-data:stackoverflow.posts_questions]
CROSS JOIN split(tags, '|') AS ss
GROUP BY ss.tags
```

Grammatically correct in SQL Server 2016 but not accepted in BigQuery, error is seen below:

[image]

Can anyone help please?

**UPDATE**

Thank you Mikhail Berlyant, interesting finding:

Here in StackOverFlow, the top 10 tags are as below:

[image]

And below is a simple piechart in DataStudio:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT Category, COUNT(*) AS TotalCat
FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions`
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(SPLIT(tags, '|')) AS Category
GROUP BY Category
```

I realized you asked for version for Legacy SQL - see below

```
#legacySQL
SELECT Category, COUNT(1) AS TotalCat
FROM (
  SELECT SPLIT(tags, '|') AS Category
  FROM [bigquery-public-data:stackoverflow.posts_questions]
)
GROUP BY Category
```